# Where is the JRE lib/ext directory from JRE13 on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, bouncycastle, java-13

I want to install the bouncy castle security.

so. when I try to move bcprov-jdk13-164.jar file, but ext folder in locate $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib is not existed. and any other folers are same that.

I need to find this directory or how to installing and using. Thanks!

Comment: No you don't. What you are trying to do is unnecessary and has been advised against for almost as long as Java exists. If an application needs a library, bundle it with the application.

Comment: @Gimby so. I don't need to install bouncycastle jar file? I don't understand well.. I try to add this file from java build path, but when I compiled, console show the error massage : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider , how can import to use library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to find this directory or how to installing and using.

Support for the "lib/ext" directory was removed in Java 9; see ["Java Platform, Standard Edition Oracle JDK 9 Migration Guide: Removed Extension Mechanism"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-2C896CA8-927C-4381-A737-B1D81D964B7B)

You now need to add any 3rd-party JAR files to the application's classpath:

- the build classpath if there are compile time dependencies,
- the runtime classpath if there are runtime dependencies.

If you are trying to use Bouncy Castle in a web container, the JAR needs to be in the container's lib directory rather than in the webapp directory.

(Instructions you may find for installing Bouncy Castle JCE providers into "lib/ext" on Java 8 are not applicable for later Java releases.)

Comment: thanks! problem is solved!

Comment: @김동균 How did you solved this problem ?